# Upper limit to the number of real and distinct roots an equation can have.

Tags: real-analysis, model-theory

An equation is formed using ONLY polynomials (including fractional powers), exponentials and logs. One such equation is shown below; a,b,c,d are real constants.
$$
ae^{x+b}-3x^2\left(\ln x^5-c\right)+\left(x^{\frac{6}{d}}-\ln\left(10x-d^8\right)\right)+\frac{ax^{-1}+b}{b^4-c^3}=0\qquad a,b,c,d,x\in\mathbb{R}.
$$
Changing the constants $a, b, c, d$ clearly gives rise to a different number of roots and there is obviously an upper limit to how many roots are obtainable in this way.

I am trying to show how the number of roots will have an upper limit (without necessarily finding this limit) but not having any luck. Eg. no matter what $a, b, c, d$ are, the equation above cannot have more than $3$ roots.

I appreciate any pointers, advice and help. Thank you.

Comment: Strictly speaking, a polynomial is an expression $\sum_{k=0}^n a_kx^k$ with $k \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Agreed but for now let's pretend k can be a fraction.

Comment: Your posting is missing several details.
Please see [this article on MathSE protocol](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236).

Comment: I don't understand : even without using any log or exp,  polynomial $(x-1)(x-2)\cdots(x-n)$ has $n$ real roots...

Comment: If you allow complex constants, there can be an infinity of roots, e.g. with $e^{ix}+e^{-ix}=2\cos x$.

Comment: Jean: that is true but the equation you propose would grow in size, whereas the one I am suggesting does not.

Comment: Jean-Armand, that is correct.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this is true, except when it's trivially false.

To make this question more precise, let $f(x,y_1,\ldots,y_n)$ be an expression formed by composition of exponentials, natural logarithms and rational functions.

Then there is a number $N$ such that for every parameter tuple $(b_1,\ldots,b_n)\in \mathbf R^n$, if the solution set  $f(x,b_1,\ldots,b_n)$ does not contain any interval, then it has at most $N$ points.

Note that it can contain an interval, for example if $f=b_1x/(x-1)-b_2x/(x-1)$, then when $b_1=b_2$, $f=0$ everywhere except $x=1$, where it is undefined. (Note that in this case, $f(x,b_1,b_2)$ is zero as an element of the function field; I think that may be the only way we have an interval of solutions, but I don't quite see the argument right now.)

The reason why this is true is that every $f$ of this form is definable in the exponential field $(\mathbf R, +, \cdot, \exp)$ which is known to be [o-minimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/O-minimal_theory) by a celebrated result of Wilkie. This means that the solution set of $f(x,\bar y)=0$ (in $\mathbf R^{1+n}$) admits an o-minimal cellular decomposition, and the number of cells in this decomposition gives $N$ (this is a weak bound, in fact a much smaller bound is more typical).

For some more background on o-minimality and cellular decomposition, see e.g. [these notes by Sergei Starchenko](https://www.fields.utoronto.ca/programs/scientific/08-09/o-minimal/geometry/Starchenko2.pdf) (I'm afraid the details are beyond the scope of an answer here).

Comment: [+1] Very interesting.

Comment: Thank you Tomasz. I will set about investigating what you have written but it sounds like the kind of thing I am looking for. The maths is a little above my grade (I teach engineering mathematics at graduate level) but I love the subject so I will follow it up.